# Получение scale ratio в коде С++ в системе Linux

Tags: c++, linux, x11, scale

Необходимо получить scale ratio(измнение масштаба отображения в настроках мониторов 100-200-300%) в коде C++.
Пробовал пролистать документацию Xrandr ничего не нашел что могло хоть как-то помочь. Получить физические DPI легко, а вот логические нет возможности найти. Необходимо получить scale без исползования Qt.
Либо все жеи если есть способ получить LogicalDPI, то тоже будет очень хорошо.

А именно scaleFactor из GNOME и Xorg.
(https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/HiDPI#X_Server)

Comment: О каких конкретно настройках мониторов речь? Подозреваю, вы хотите что-то DE-специфичное, что в чистом x11/xrandr отсутствует

Comment: @andreymal  Когда на мониторах высокого разрешения, мы можем увеличивать масштаб системы/приложений. Было бы неплохо получить сам масштаб, ну или хотя бы logical dpi.

Comment: Увеличивать где и как? О чём конкретно речь?

Comment: @andreymal похожий функционал выполняет функция из WINAPI - GetScaleFactorForMonitor. (https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shellscalingapi/nf-shellscalingapi-getscalefactorformonitor)

Comment: Это-то понятно, а в вашем линуксе-то какие конкретно настройки масштабирования вас интересуют? Их можно насчитать больше десятка, и о чём конкретно речь — непонятно

Comment: Какой именно scaleFactor? Повторюсь, этих scaleFactor'ов больше десятка, а вы всё не хотите сознаваться, какой используете вы

Comment: @andreymal хотелось бы получить такой же реузльтат в коде как и от функции выше (из винапи), а именно сам scaleFactor интерфейса системы. Как-то так

Comment: Ладно, раз вы не хотите сознаваться, вот вам вместо ответа статья: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/HiDPI — читайте и выбирайте нужный вам scaleFactor

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/116050/discussion-between-mitski-fys-and-andreymal).

Comment: Ответ [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28582082/reading-gsettings-from-c-program). В glibmm есть привязка C ++ к gsettings

Comment: @Mitski_fys Оно не про "систему Linux", а то ли про гном, то ли про гном в убунте. Соответственно, про Window Maker на слаквари оно ничего не скажет. Если у WM вообще есть такое понятие.